# How to update value of remarks using Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my form in Zend on remarks part:

```
$remarks = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('remarks');
$remarks->setLabel('Check this if your task is done')
        ->setCheckedValue(true);
```

And this is my controller:

```
if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
    $id = (int)$form->getValue('tid');
    $taskname = $form->getValue('taskname');
    $startdate  = $form->getValue('startdate');
    $endate     = $form->getValue('endate');
    $remarks    = $form->getValue('remarks');
    $task = new Application_Model_DbTable_Task();
    if ($remarks == 1) { 
        $task->updateTask($id , $taskname , $startdate , $endate , $remarks);
    } elseif ($remarks == 0) {
        $task->updateTask($id , $taskname , $startdate , $endate);
    }
    $this->_helper->redirector('index');
```

The defalut value of my remarks in my database is `0` and I want to change its value to `1` using checkbox in Zend please help thank you

This is my `DBTable` model

```
protected $_name = 'task';

public function getTask($id)
{
    $id = (int)$id ;
    $row = $this->fetchrow('tid = '. $id );
    if (!$row) {
        throw new Exeption("Sorry could not find row $row");
    }
    return $row->toArray();
}

public function addTask($taskname , $startdate , $endate)
{
    $data = array(
            'taskname'  => $taskname ,
            'startdate' => $startdate  ,
            'endate'    => $endate ,
            );
    $this->insert($data);
}

public function updateTask($id ,$taskname , $startdate , $endate)
{
    $data = array(
            'taskname'  => $taskname ,
            'startdate' => $startdate ,
            'endate'    => $endate ,
            'remarks'   => $remarks ,
            );
    $this->update($data , 'tid= ' . (int)$id);
}
```

thank for your answers i just edit my code like this

```
   public function updateTask($id ,$taskname , $startdate , $endate, $remarks )
```

and it works fine thanks also to Jay Bhatt for asking my codes in my Application_Model_DbTable_Task() model i just remembered what i have to do

Comment: Post the code of your Application_Model_DbTable_Task() model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `$remarks` parameter in your `updateTask` function of your model.
ie, replace

```
public function updateTask($id ,$taskname , $startdate , $endate)
```

by

```
public function updateTask($id ,$taskname , $startdate , $endate, $remarks = 0)
```